# How to use flexible empty box in div tag in angular, which should adjust during responsive check

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I m trying to display a empty box with any color in a div tag, which must fit in during responsive check in angular 8.

suggest me any idea.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow..!! Can you share a code that you have done so far?

Comment: i have no idea, i have to start

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please rewrite your quesion and make it more detailed.
What do you mean by "responsive check"?

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to answer your question with the details provided.

Is this all you want it to be?

```css
#box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```